# Field collection does not show on the page

Tags: 8, entities

I've installed filed collection on drupal 8 version. Now I'm trying to add field collection named "field_ingredients_second" to a content type. And then I've added fields to this newly created field collections. After that I've added values in edit mode. However, when I open it in a view mode it does not show anything there.

I've also configured view for it and also placed it block layout. Inside block layout I've configured my mustache file.

Inside my mustache file I've

```
It shows here 
{{#field_ingredients_second}}
it does not show anything
{{/field_ingredients_second}}
& It shows here also
```

In the output "It shows here & It shows here also " is displayed but not the values from the tags inside. Can anyone help me with this. Why field collection is not displayed on the page

Comment: If you've just started the project: Paragraphs is likely to replace field collection for Drupal 8. Field collection is on its way to being deprecated. It is recommended to use paragraphs instead of field collection for Drupal 8 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are leaving out some details, neither Drupal 7 or 8 us Mustache templates, they use TPL and Twig respectively.

If this is Drupal 7, you should be doing:

```
print $content['field_ingredients_second'];
```

In Drupal 8, you would do this:

```
{{ content.field_ingredients_second }}
```

Other than that, you would need to use a debugger to figure out what variables are being sent into the template.

edit: 4k4 is right though, if this is Drupal 8, don't use Field Collection. Use Paragraphs.

Comment: I'm on Drupal 8 and using Mustache templates. Can you please tell me how to debug and figure out what variable are being sent?

Comment: Installed paragraph module onto my site. Still the same issue added this filed to my content type "field_new_multiple_ingredients_" and inside my mustache file it is not rendered any other plain text filed or any other thing is render in the mustache file

Comment: I have no idea how you are using Mustache.